# Adding popup support to the theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have added a popup to my wordpress site using popup builder (https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-builder/). I am using a custom theme built by me and the pop-up is not displaying when that theme is activated. When I use one of the preloaded themes in wordpress, it works. I have tried a couple of other plugins too. All of them work on the preloaded themes but not on custom theme. Is there something I should add to my theme files to enable popup support?

Comment: Does your theme use `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I wasn't. Thanks a lot. That fixed the issue.